# stackoverflowerror on recursive method with arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, trie

I am see an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. I hope to know what is wrong with the code below.

```
public void addWord(String word){
    addWord(word,root,0);
}

private void addWord(String word,Node root,int pos)
{
    for(Node c:root.children)
    {
        if(word.charAt(pos)==c.letter)
        {
            addWord(word,c,pos++);
        }
    }
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.letter=word.charAt(pos);
    temp.children=new ArrayList<Node>();
    root.children.add(temp);
    if(pos==word.length()-1)
    {
        temp.terminus=true;
        return;
    }
    if(pos<word.length()-1)
    {
        addWord(word,temp,pos++);
    }
}
```

Comment: If other people are reading/using this, it's a lot more readable to use more spaces, like after commas, after an if, before and after '==', etc.

Answer (score 6):

In essence, stack overflow comes from the fact that your method keeps being called recursively and the recursion never ends.

One possible problem is this call:

```
addWord(word,temp,pos++);
```

It is equivalent to

```
addWord(word,temp,pos);
pos = pos + 1;
```

You probably mean:

```
addWord(word,temp,++pos);
```

which would be equivalent to

```
pos = pos + 1;
addWord(word,temp,pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simpler version of `addWord()`:

```
private void addWord(String word, Node aRoot, int pos) {

    if (pos == word.length())
        return;

    for (Node c : aRoot.children) {
        if (word.charAt(pos) == c.letter) {
            addWord(word, c, pos+1);
            return;
        }
    }

    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.letter = word.charAt(pos);
    temp.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    temp.terminus = pos == word.length() - 1;

    aRoot.children.add(temp);
    addWord(word, temp, pos+1);

}
```

The original version in your code had a couple of problems with base cases, and with the recursive calls. As a general rule, you should avoid changing the values of a method's parameters (the `pos++` part).

I'm guessing you're building a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure, and I anticipate that you're gonna have problems with that `terminus` attribute. Think about it, if you add several words with common prefixes, which would be the terminus node? do you intend to add several nodes with the same `letter` at the same level, or do you want to share nodes at the same level with the same letter? in the latter case, what would be the value of the `terminus` attribute?

To make my point clear, draw a diagram showing how would you like your Trie to look like after executing the following code (paying close attention to the value of `terminus` in each node), and see if the above implementation gives the result you expect.

```
Test t = new Test();
t.addWord("a");
t.addWord("abc");
t.addWord("ab");
```